# How to display post in WordPress based on parent category?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my structure:

```
+Parent1
  -Child Cat 1
  -Child Cat 2

+Parent2
  -Child Cat 4
  -Child Cat 5
```

--> 2 posts have been published in child category 1

--> 3 posts have been published in child category 2

--> 7 posts have been published in child category 4

--> 9 posts have been published in child category 5

No posts have been published directly in parent1 and parent2. Published in child category only.

I want the posts of the child category to be displayed in the corresponding parent category.

For example, in parent category 1, all 5 child category posts(2+3) should be displayed.

And in parent category 2, all 16 child posts(7+9) should be displayed.

Also, the priority of displaying posts in the parent category 1&2 should be with sticky posts.

This is my code:

```html
    global $post;
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
    
    $myposts = get_posts(
        array(
                'posts_per_page'=>20,
                'offset' => 0,
                'cat' => $category,
                'post_status'=>'publish',
                'order'=>'ASC',
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => 0
        ),
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because

1. `get_the_category` only returns the categories that are assigned to that post - and it looks like you are specifically limiting it to the first category.
2. `cat` doesn't traverse upward to parent categories. It does return posts of child categories.

To do what you want, get the `parent` property from the category object:

```
global $post;
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
    // category parent
    $category_parent = $category[0]->parent; 
    // Build the category array 
    $category_array = [ $category, $category_parent ];
   
    
    $myposts = get_posts(
        array(
                'posts_per_page'=>20,
                'offset' => 0,
                'category__in' => $category_array, // set the array here.
                'post_status'=>'publish',
                'order'=>'ASC',
        ),
    );
```

You can remove `ignore_sticky_posts` since the default value is already false, can you can use `category__in` instead of `cat` to pass an array of categories.

This is untested, but should work. If it doesn't, try doing:

```
`'cat' => implode(',', $category_array )`
```

Instead of the `category__in`.

Based on your updated question, use `get_term_children` ([documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_children/)) or you should just be able to pass the parent category ID to the query, since `cat => id` *should* get the posts of that category, including children.

```
    global $post;
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $category = $category[0]->cat_ID;
    // category parent
    $category_parent = $category[0]->parent;
    // Get all the children categories
    $children_categories = get_term_children( $category_parent, 'category' ); 
    // Build the category including the parent and the children of that parent. 
    $category_array = [ $children_categories, $category_parent ];
   
    /* this passes the parent and children categories. */
    $myposts = get_posts(
        array(
                'posts_per_page'=>20,
                'offset' => 0,
                'cat' => implode(',', $category_array ),
                'post_status'=>'publish',
                'order'=>'ASC',
        ),
    );

    /* ALTERNATIVE: this only passes the parent ID */
    $myposts = get_posts(
        array(
                'posts_per_page'=>20,
                'offset' => 0,
                'cat' => $category_parent,
                'post_status'=>'publish',
                'order'=>'ASC',
        ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Second suggestion of your code is work. But it also shows the posts of other categories. (other parent and child that published in site). I want to show only the posts of this category.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you want:  _I want to display all posts, that are in the parent and child categories._ is what you asked and that's what this does. Can you edit your question to explain - using your example categories, what you want?

Comment: I have a category called X
which has a subcategory named X1 and X2
I also have a category called Y.which has a subcategory called Y1 and Y2.

A large number of posts have been published in the X1 and X2 and Y1 and Y2 categories.
I want all these posts to be displayed in category X (parent).

Your code will also display Y category content in X category.That should not be shown.

Comment: Why are posts from category Y showing up in category X? It should not be like this.

Comment: Update the part in your question about your category structure. If you have posts that have subcategories that have different parents, I'm still not sure what posts you are expecting to show under the X parent. Edit your question to show in more detail what you expect. That would be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you. My question has been changed.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Updated the answer. Hopefully it gets closer to what you want.